# numpy create new 2D array from existing array,column values as indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

So I have a numpy array of shape ( 4950,3) .From this array , i need to create new array ( matrix) whose values and indices are from the existing array.

Specifically,

> Array1  = array([   [  0.,1.,0.4284256 ],
>   [0.,2.,0.38090856],
>   [1., 2.,0.32901526] ] ).

```
new Array2 [0,1] = 0.4284256 , Array2[0,2]=0.38090856 and Array2[1,2]= 0.32901526
```

Right now i use for loop , but i am thinking there has to be an efficient way.
[A1 and A2 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX6oc.png)

```
for i in range(A1.shape[0]):
    A2[ A1[i,0], A1[i,1] ] = A1[i,2]
```

Comment: What would be the shape of your new array? Could you give the print example of your Array2? It's possible to reshape arrays but there are rules regarding dimensions.

Comment: You wan to map the first 2 elements in *Array1* to the coordinates in *Array2*. I don't think **reshape** would help you here. You best bet is loop through, or use *list comprehension* for shorter code.

Comment: But if he wants to do that why would the third element of it's last row in array1 be in position 1,2 in array2? What is the rule?

Comment: Yes, i want to map the first 2 elements in Array1 to be the co-ordinates of Array2. Say , Array1 has row [1,2,33] then, "1" is x-cordinate,"2" is 'y-cordinate'  and '33' is the value at A2[x][y] . ie i need to set A[1,2]=33.

Comment: @armatita The shape could be max value at first column ,max value at second column of A1. or to ease it up, we can say shape(100,100) since my max value of first column of A1  will be 99.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You can index directly the values of one array using the Integer values from another.

```
import numpy as np
Array1 = np.array([ [ 0.,1.,0.4284256 ], [0.,2.,0.38090856], [1., 2.,0.32901526] ] )
Array2 = np.zeros(Array1.shape)
Array2[np.int_(Array1[:,0]),np.int_(Array1[:,1])] = Array1[:,2]
print(Array2)
```

, result is:

```
[[ 0.          0.4284256   0.38090856]
 [ 0.          0.          0.32901526]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: I don't think ur code works if there are more than 3 rows ! Now it is working since u have 3 rows .

Comment: The indexing works for any number of rows, you just have to make sure that the number of elements you are indexing is the number of values you are attributing. You can index both sides of the instruction.